# Synchronizing two enumerables

Tags: c#, linq, synchronization, ienumerable

I have two collections.

```
  var a = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "j" };
  var b = new List<string>() { "a", "c", "d", "h", "i" };
```

And I would like to do some action on the item in case it's missing in one collection or another.

```
public static Synchronize<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Action<T> firstSynchronizer, Action<T> secondSynchronizer)
{
  var firstUnique = first.Distinct();
  var secondUnique = second.Distinct();
  foreach (var item in firstUnique)
  {
    if (!secondUnique.Contains(item)) firstSynchronizer(item);
  }
  foreach (var item in second.Distinct())
  {
    if (!firstUnique.Contains(item)) secondSynchronizer(item);
  }
}
```

This is what I got but I am not happy with it. I can't help but wonder if there's a better way to implement this, because I think `Distinct()` is pretty big performance hit and also I am not sure if it's better to iterate whole second Enumerable and check if item is not present in first Enumerable already (like above) or if it would be better to iterate `second.Except(first)`? What do you guys think?

I call it like this:

```
  var a = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "j" };
  var b = new List<string>() { "a", "c", "d", "h", "i" };
  Synchronize(a.ToArray(), b.ToArray(), t => b.Add(t), t => a.Add(t));
```

I call `ToArray()` so collections don't get changed while being iterated over and lambdas just add missing elements to respective lists.

Also, this is just a test implementation. In production environment, Enumerables won't be of same type. This is intended to be used to sync remote and local storage. In future, Enumerable first will be for example `ICollection<DummyRemoteItem>` and Enumerable second will be `List<IO.FileSystemInfo>`. But I want it to be more generic. To make it possible to work with different collections, I think I would propose another type parameter and a `Func<T1, T2, bool>` for comparing items. That would be a best approach, right?

Generally, what's the best way to implement insides of

```
Synchronize<T>(IEnumerable<T> first,IEnumerable<T> second,Action<T> firstSynchronizer,Action<T> secondSynchronizer)
```

and

```
Synchronize<TFirst, TSecond>(IEnumerable<TFirst> first,IEnumerable<TSecond> second,Action<TFirst> firstSynchronizer,Action<TSecond> secondSynchronizer, Func<TFirst, TSecond, bool> predicate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq full outer join is your friend here.

Here's an implementation (from [here](http://blogs.geniuscode.net/RyanDHatch/?p=116))

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> FullOuterJoin<T1, T2>
   (this IEnumerable<T1> one, IEnumerable<T2> two, Func<T1,T2,bool> match)
{
 var left = from a in one
   from b in two.Where((b) => match(a, b)).DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new Tuple<T1, T2>(a, b);

 var right = from b in two
   from a in one.Where((a) => match(a, b)).DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new Tuple<T1, T2>(a, b);

 return left.Concat(right).Distinct();
}
```

so:

```
a.FullOuterJoin(b,a=>a,b=>b,(a,b)=>new {a,b})
```

and look for nulls in the resulting enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Except` and `Intersect` methods to find the differences or identical items between two enumerable sources. MSDN has a lot of resources on both [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) and [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx).

As for the comment about `Distinct()` having an expensive performance hit I would suspect that the hit is minor and trying to optimize would be to do so prematurely.

Comment: I preffered answer featuring full outer join, but thanks for your answer too!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most elegant way would be to use sets. In .NET HashSet might be what you are looking for,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495294.aspx

Comment: I preffered answer featuring full outer join, but thanks for your answer too!

Answer (score 0):

The following could be used if the items in collections are of two different types:

```
 class CollectionSynchronizer<TSource, TDestination>
    {
        public Func<TSource, TDestination, bool> CompareFunc { get; set; }
        public Action<TDestination> RemoveAction { get; set; }
        public Action<TSource> AddAction { get; set; }
        public Action<TSource, TDestination> UpdateAction { get; set; }

        public void Synchronizer(ICollection<TSource> sourceItems, ICollection<TDestination> destinationItems)
        {
            // Remove items not in source from destination
            RemoveItems(sourceItems, destinationItems);

            // Add items in source to destination 
            AddOrUpdateItems(sourceItems, destinationItems);
        }

        private void RemoveItems(ICollection<TSource> sourceCollection, ICollection<TDestination> destinationCollection)
        {
            foreach (var destinationItem in destinationCollection.ToArray())
            {
                var sourceItem = sourceCollection.FirstOrDefault(item => CompareFunc(item, destinationItem));

                if (sourceItem == null)
                {
                    RemoveAction(destinationItem);
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddOrUpdateItems(ICollection<TSource> sourceCollection, ICollection<TDestination> destinationCollection)
        {
            var destinationList = destinationCollection.ToList();
            foreach (var sourceItem in sourceCollection)
            {
                var destinationItem = destinationList.FirstOrDefault(item => CompareFunc(sourceItem, item));

                if (destinationItem == null)
                {
                    AddAction(sourceItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdateAction(sourceItem, destinationItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the usage would be like this:

```
var collectionSynchronizer = new CollectionSynchronizer<string, ContentImageEntity>
            {
                CompareFunc = (communityImage, contentImage) => communityImage == contentImage.Name,
                AddAction = sourceItem =>
                {
                    var contentEntityImage = _contentImageProvider.Create(sourceItem);
                    contentEntityImages.Add(contentEntityImage);
                },
                UpdateAction = (communityImage, contentImage) =>
                {
                    _contentImageProvider.Update(contentImage);
                },
                RemoveAction = contentImage =>
                {
                    contentEntityImages.Remove(contentImage);
                }
            };

            collectionSynchronizer.Synchronizer(externalContentImages, contentEntityImages);
```